# Get img alt which parent a's href is something

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="related-posts">
    <a href="http://localhost">
        <img width="100" height="100" src="test.jpg" alt="alt">
    </a>
    <a href="http://localhost/1">  
        <img src=" test1.jpg" alt="Hello world!">
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to get the `alt` value of the `img` whose parent is the `a` with a `href` of `http://localhost`. What code can I use to get that value?

Comment: That's an invalid HTML, didn't close the img tag. Check.

Comment: Where are you stuck? jQuery's documentation (and CSS's documentation) is fairly clear about how to find elements based on attribute values, and how to find elements that are descendants of other elements.

Comment: Thanks , but  now I  can't edit  code  in  stackoverflow . In my local  it  is  normally

Comment: @NorayrManukyan Can't edit?

Comment: Actually @T.J.Crowder is right, I should not have answered this question as it does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// will match http://localhost only:
$('a[href="http://localhost"]').find('img').attr('alt'); 

// will match links hreffing to URLs starting with http://localhost 
$('a[href^="http://localhost"]').find('img').attr('alt');
```

Comment: This could be smaller by doing: `$("a[href*='http://localhost'] > img ").attr("alt");`

Comment: Assuming the **direct** child structure does not change, yes.

Comment: And maybe OP wants strict matching of attribute value, but that's not really clear so...  you got my vote

Comment: Semi-offtopic, but `.find()` would: *get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.*. So your solution is also assuming the child structure doesn't change. The image would have to be the first image (since `.attr()` grabs the first attribute when presented with an array).

Still a good solution, upvoted.

Comment: I edited post because `*=` isn't for starting but containing

Comment: Yeah right, thanks for editing!